# resolution in WPF

Tags: wpf, grid, resolution

In my applcaiton,i make Grid of size Grid Width="1300.441" Height="80",
Its working fien in this resolution.But when i changed my resolution to 1152 width,quater of application get out of the desktop.
How can i avoid that?
I want to display full page in all resolution.
Pls help me

Comment: Can you post reason why you want to fix your grid size, infact grid is designed for dynamic sizing, and for fixed sizes, you can simply use Canvas thats easy to design n fast.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF, the pixel size is 1/96 inch. There's no other resolution. It seems that your content is 13.54626 inches wide. My guess is that this is an XPS document or a raster or something? In this case, there is no way to display the whole thing in 1152 pixels at 100% without cropping and needing to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

You can place your grid inside a `ViewBox` element, it will scale everything down to whatever resolution you need.

```
<ViewBox Width="1000">
    <Grid Width="1300.441">
    ...
    </Grid>
</ViewBox>
```